# TypeError: Rect argument is invalid when i try to jump in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to jump but I get the error:

> TypeError: Rect argument is invalid

I learnt this off of youtube, by the way.

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init() 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("First game!")


gubbe_x = 50
gubbe_y = 50
gubbe_vel = 0.1
gubbe_width = 40
gubbe_height = 50
isjump = False
jumpCount = 10

run = True
running = True 
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    #write code in forloop line
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (gubbe_x, gubbe_y, gubbe_width, gubbe_height))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and gubbe_x < 500 - gubbe_width - gubbe_vel:
        gubbe_x += gubbe_vel
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and gubbe_x > gubbe_vel:
        gubbe_x -= gubbe_vel
    if not (isjump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and gubbe_y > gubbe_vel:
            gubbe_y -= gubbe_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and gubbe_y < 500 - gubbe_height - gubbe_vel:
            gubbe_y += gubbe_vel
        
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isjump = True
        
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            gubbe_y -= jumpCount ** 1.5 * 0.05
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isjump == False
            jumpCount = 10


    
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The result of `-1 ** 1.5` is a complex number.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

The result of `-1 ** 1.5` is a complex number. Most likely you tried to do the following:

<s>`gubbe_y -= jumpCount ** 1.5 * 0.05`</s>

```py
gubbe_y -= (1 if jumpCount > 0 else -1) *  abs(jumpCount) ** 1.5  * 0.05
```

Further more there is a typo in the les case:

<s>`isjump == False`</s>

```py
isjump = False
```

---

See the example:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    if not (isjump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and gubbe_y > gubbe_vel:
            gubbe_y -= gubbe_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and gubbe_y < 500 - gubbe_height - gubbe_vel:
            gubbe_y += gubbe_vel
        
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isjump = True
        
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            gubbe_y -= (1 if jumpCount > 0 else -1) *  abs(jumpCount) ** 1.5  * 0.05
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isjump = False
            jumpCount = 10

    # [...]
```